# PCB board to board connector with thin footprint

Tags: pcb, rf, pcb-design, surface-mount, interconnect

I am trying to design a small PCB that goes into a bigger PCB.
My small PCB is mounting a very sensitive fragile sensor on the top surface that has to be wire bonded to the PCB, so I am trying to design a smaller PCB that can be surface mounted to the bigger PCB.
The smaller PCB will mount the sensor on top and using vias all the connections will be taken to the bottom plane of the PCB.
I am looking for some kind of a footprint that I can use for interconnecting the two PCB boards. I am looking for a very thin footprint and very low noise.
Any ideas that can help are appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of those available, just look at your distributor of choice.

Comment: @Hearth Can you please link me at some examples? I am trying to get some ideas and examples as a starting point to the design.

Comment: That would make this a shopping question, and thus off topic. Seriously, just go to the board-to-board connectors section of your distributor of choice and use the parametric search.

Comment: @Hearth Well Thanks! Just did a search and found a bunch of them. Was easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put plated half holes on the edge of the small board and then solder it directly to the large board.  This skips having a connector all-together.

Many board manufacturers (even cheap ones such as PCB way) can do this.
https://www.pcbway.com/pcb_prototype/What_are_Plated_Half_Holes_Castellated_Holes_.html
[image]

Some examaples of this being done on commercial modules are...

- Microchip MRF24J40MA wireless module.  As you can see there are plated solder contacts on the edge of the board.
  https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MRF24J40MA
  [image]
- HOPERF RFM75W wireless module.  Here they put both a plated half hole and through hole on each contact, so you can solder either directly to a board or to a header.
  https://www.hoperf.com/modules/2.4g/RFM75.html
  [image]